# Make Image Wrap Around Screen Edge using CMMotionManager?

Tags: ios, objective-c

What I am trying to accomplish is moving a UIImageView to the top edge of the iPhone's screen and then keep moving it up, but once the image passes the top edge, have it appear at the bottom of the screen, as it continues moving through.
also lett to right and right to left

it will be move through Accelerometer and also on  UISwipeGesture
i used two same images but not working properly
if anyone have example ,please share

it is possible with one image?

[image]

If anyone know about this task let me know.

thanks.

Comment: i think you can do it with UIKITDynamics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using Accelerometer**

You have to use two same images

here i am using 1) _imageView  2) _imgViewTemp

```
         - (void)startUpdateAccelerometer:(UIImageView*)ImgView1 view:(UIView*)boundView
          {
          if ([self.mManager isAccelerometerAvailable] == YES) {
    // self.mManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 1.0/10000.0;
            [self.mManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error)
         {
           CGRect imgFrame = _imageView.frame;

            if(isWindowActive){

             imgFrame.origin.x -=accelerometerData.acceleration.y*8.0 ;

             if(!CGRectContainsRect(self.view.bounds, imgFrame))
                 imgFrame.origin.x = _imageView.frame.origin.x;

             imgFrame.origin.y -=accelerometerData.acceleration.x *8.0;
             if(!CGRectContainsRect(self.view.bounds, imgFrame))
                 imgFrame.origin.y = _imageView.frame.origin.y;
             _imageView.frame = imgFrame;

         }
         else{
             imgFrame.origin.x -=accelerometerData.acceleration.y*8.0 ;
             imgFrame.origin.y -=accelerometerData.acceleration.x *8.0;
             if(CGRectContainsRect(boundView.frame, _imageView.frame)){

                 _imgViewTemp.hidden=YES;
             }
             _imageView.frame=imgFrame;
             if ((_imageView.frame.origin.y>_bounderView.frame.size.height-_imageView.frame.size.height && _imageView.frame.origin.x>_bounderView.frame.size.width-_imageView.frame.size.width) ){
                 NSLog(@"-x hidden");
                 _imageView.frame=CGRectMake(_imageView.frame.origin.x, 0, _imageView.frame.size.width, _imageView.frame.size.height);
                 _imgViewTemp.frame=CGRectMake(_imgViewTemp.frame.origin.x, 0,_imageView.frame.size.width, _imageView.frame.size.height);
                 return ;
             }
             else if ((_imageView.frame.origin.y>_bounderView.frame.size.height-_imageView.frame.size.height && _imageView.frame.origin.x<0) ){
                 NSLog(@"-x hidden");
                 _imageView.frame=CGRectMake(_imageView.frame.origin.x, 0,_imageView.frame.size.width, _imageView.frame.size.height);
                 _imgViewTemp.frame=CGRectMake(_imgViewTemp.frame.origin.x, 0, _imageView.frame.size.width, _imageView.frame.size.height);
                 return ;
             }
             else if (_imageView.frame.origin.y<0 && _imageView.frame.origin.x>_bounderView.frame.size.width-_imageView.frame.size.width) {
                 _imageView.frame=CGRectMake(_imageView.frame.origin.x, _bounderView.frame.size.height-_imageView.frame.size.height,_imageView.frame.size.width, _imageView.frame.size.height);
                 _imgViewTemp.frame=CGRectMake(_imgViewTemp.frame.origin.x,_bounderView.frame.size.height-_imageView.frame.size.height,_imageView.frame.size.width, _imageView.frame.size.height);
                 return ;

             }else  if (_imageView.frame.origin.y<0 && _imageView.frame.origin.x<0) {
                 _imageView.frame=CGRectMake(_imageView.frame.origin.x, _bounderView.frame.size.height-_imageView.frame.size.height, _imageView.frame.size.width, _imageView.frame.size.height);
                 _imgViewTemp.frame=CGRectMake(_imgViewTemp.frame.origin.x,_bounderView.frame.size.height-_imageView.frame.size.height,_imageView.frame.size.width, _imageView.frame.size.height);
                 return ;
             }
             else if (imgFrame.origin.x<0) {
                 if (imgFrame.origin.x<-_imageView.frame.size.width) {
                     NSLog(@"less 70");
                     _imgViewTemp.hidden=YES;
                     _imageView.frame=_imgViewTemp.frame;
                 }else{
                     _imgViewTemp.hidden=NO;
                     _imgViewTemp.frame=CGRectMake(_bounderView.frame.size.width+imgFrame.origin.x, imgFrame.origin.y, _imageView.frame.size.width,  _imageView.frame.size.height);
                 }
             }
             else if (imgFrame.origin.x>_bounderView.frame.size.width-_imageView.frame.size.width){
                 if (imgFrame.origin.x>_bounderView.frame.size.width) {
                     _imgViewTemp.hidden=YES;
                     _imageView.frame=_imgViewTemp.frame;
                 }else{
                     _imgViewTemp.hidden=NO;
                     _imgViewTemp.frame=CGRectMake(-(_bounderView.frame.size.width-imgFrame.origin.x), imgFrame.origin.y, _imageView.frame.size.width,  _imageView.frame.size.height);
                 }
             }
             else if (imgFrame.origin.y<0){
                 if (imgFrame.origin.y<-_imageView.frame.size.height) {
                     _imgViewTemp.hidden=YES;
                     _imageView.frame=_imgViewTemp.frame;

                 }else{
                     _imgViewTemp.hidden=NO;
                     _imgViewTemp.frame=CGRectMake(imgFrame.origin.x,_bounderView.frame.size.height+imgFrame.origin.y, _imageView.frame.size.width,  _imageView.frame.size.height);
                 }
             }
             else if (imgFrame.origin.y>_bounderView.frame.size.height-imgFrame.size.height){
                 if (imgFrame.origin.y>_bounderView.frame.size.height) {
                     _imgViewTemp.hidden=YES;
                     _imageView.frame=_imgViewTemp.frame;
                 }else{
                     _imgViewTemp.hidden=NO;
                     _imgViewTemp.frame=CGRectMake(imgFrame.origin.x,-(_bounderView.frame.size.height-imgFrame.origin.y), _imageView.frame.size.width,  _imageView.frame.size.height);
                 }
             }

         }
      }];
   }
}
```

**Using Timer**

```
   NSTimer  *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.004 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
  [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];


 -(void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timerData{

          UIImageView *imgView=_imageView;//firstimage
          NSInteger Xpos=imgView.frame.origin.x;
          NSInteger Ypos=imgView.frame.origin.y;
         if (movingPostion==Left) {
           Xpos-=1;
          }
         if (movingPostion==Right) {
           Xpos+=1;
          }
         if (movingPostion==Up) {
           Ypos-=1;
          }
         if (movingPostion==Down) {
           Ypos+=1;
      }

        imgView.frame =  CGRectMake(Xpos, Ypos, _imageView.frame.size.width, _imageView.frame.size.height);
        CGRect imgFrame = imgView.frame;
    _imageView.frame=imgFrame;
        if ((imgFrame.origin.y<0 && imgFrame.origin.x<0) || (imgFrame.origin.y<0 && imgFrame.origin.x>_bounderView.frame.size.width-_imageView.frame.size.width)) {
        imgFrame.origin.y=_bounderView.frame.size.height+imgFrame.origin.y;
        _imageView.frame=imgFrame;
        return;
    }else if((imgFrame.origin.y >_bounderView.frame.size.height && imgFrame.origin.x<0 ) || (imgFrame.origin.y>_bounderView.frame.size.height && imgFrame.origin.x>_bounderView.frame.size.width)){
        imgFrame.origin.y=-(_bounderView.frame.size.height-imgFrame.origin.y);
        _imageView.frame=imgFrame;
        return;
    }
    else if (imgFrame.origin.x<0 ) {
        if (imgFrame.origin.x<-_imageView.frame.size.width) {
            _imgViewTemp.hidden=YES;
            _imageView.frame=_imgViewTemp.frame;
        }else{
            _imgViewTemp.hidden=NO;
            _imgViewTemp.frame=CGRectMake(_bounderView.frame.size.width+imgFrame.origin.x, imgFrame.origin.y, _imageView.frame.size.width,  _imageView.frame.size.height);
        }
    }
    else if (imgFrame.origin.x>_bounderView.frame.size.width-_imageView.frame.size.width){
        if (imgFrame.origin.x>_bounderView.frame.size.width) {
            _imgViewTemp.hidden=YES;
            _imageView.frame=_imgViewTemp.frame;
        }else{
            _imgViewTemp.hidden=NO;
            _imgViewTemp.frame=CGRectMake(-(_bounderView.frame.size.width-imgFrame.origin.x), imgFrame.origin.y, _imageView.frame.size.width,  _imageView.frame.size.height);
        }
    }
    else if (imgFrame.origin.y<0){

        if (imgFrame.origin.y<-_imageView.frame.size.height) {
            _imgViewTemp.hidden=YES;
            _imageView.frame=_imgViewTemp.frame;

        }else{
            _imgViewTemp.hidden=NO;
            _imgViewTemp.frame=CGRectMake(imgFrame.origin.x,_bounderView.frame.size.height+imgFrame.origin.y, _imageView.frame.size.width,  _imageView.frame.size.height);
        }
    }
    else if (imgFrame.origin.y>_bounderView.frame.size.height-imgFrame.size.height ){
        if (imgFrame.origin.y>_bounderView.frame.size.height) {
            _imgViewTemp.hidden=YES;
            _imageView.frame=_imgViewTemp.frame;
        }else{
            _imgViewTemp.hidden=NO;
            _imgViewTemp.frame=CGRectMake(imgFrame.origin.x,-(_bounderView.frame.size.height-imgFrame.origin.y), _imageView.frame.size.width,  _imageView.frame.size.height);
        }


}
```